# How to check if a UIView is out of its superview bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uiview

I have a view with a pan gesture and a UIPushBehavior hooked up to it an wanted to know if its possible to check when the view is out the superviews bounds. Basically the user tosses the view and I want to run some animation when the view is out of the screen. Couldn't figure out how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you want to check if it is entirely out of it's superview bounds you can do this

```
if (!CGRectContainsRect(view.superview.bounds, view.frame))
{
    //view is completely out of bounds of its super view.
}
```

If you want to check if just part of it is out of bounds you can do

```
if (!CGRectEqualToRect(CGRectIntersection(view.superview.bounds, view.frame), view.frame))
{
   //view is partially out of bounds
}
```

Comment: Just tried this and it seems that its getting called even when the view is still in the bounds of the superview :/

Comment: If it help what I'm doing is based off of this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/71828/uikit-dynamics-tutorial-tossing-views

Comment: Basically I want to do things once the view is off the screen

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question.  You will need to put that code in the action for your gesture recognizer.

Comment: Did that, the code I put in the is getting called even when the view is still in the bounds

Comment: Can you post your code for how you set up your gesture recognizer and for your action method?

Comment: I can but it's really long, is there a specific part?

Comment: Just the creation of the recognizer and the action method with the check for the view being out of bounds.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Philipp's answer on partially out of bounds check is not fully correct in this line:
`v1.bounds.intersection(v2.frame).width > 0) && (v1.bounds.intersection(v2.frame).height > 0`

Intersection size can be bigger than zero and still the view would lie inside the superview bounds.

Also it turned out that I can't use `equal(to: CGRect)` safely because of CGFloat accuracy.

Here is corrected version:

```
func outOfSuperviewBounds() -> Bool {
  guard let superview = self.superview else {
    return true
  }
  let intersectedFrame = superview.bounds.intersection(self.frame)
  let isInBounds = fabs(intersectedFrame.origin.x - self.frame.origin.x) < 1 &&
                   fabs(intersectedFrame.origin.y - self.frame.origin.y) < 1 &&
                   fabs(intersectedFrame.size.width - self.frame.size.width) < 1 &&
                   fabs(intersectedFrame.size.height - self.frame.size.height) < 1
  return !isInBounds
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**

As pointed out, this answer is not entirely correct, please refer to the more upvoted one.

In Swift 3:

```
    let v1 = UIView()
    v1.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
    v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    view.addSubview(v1)

    let v2 = UIView()
    v2.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    v2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    view.addSubview(v2)

    if (v1.bounds.contains(v2.frame))
    {
        //view is completely inside super view.
    }
    //this should be an or test
    if (v1.bounds.intersection(v2.frame).width > 0) || (v1.bounds.intersection(v2.frame).height > 0)
    {
        //view is partially out of bounds
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 5

```
func isView(_ innerView: UIView, outOfViewFrame outerViewFrame: CGRect) -> Bool {
        let intersectedFrame = outerViewFrame.intersection(innerView.frame)
        let isInBounds = abs(intersectedFrame.origin.x - innerView.frame.origin.x) < 1 &&
            abs(intersectedFrame.origin.y - innerView.frame.origin.y) < 1 &&
            abs(intersectedFrame.size.width - innerView.frame.size.width) < 1 &&
            abs(intersectedFrame.size.height - innerView.frame.size.height) < 1
        return !isInBounds
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 5 version on accepted answer:

```
// Full
if subview.superview!.bounds.contains(subview.frame) { 
  // Do something 
}

// Partial
let intersection = subview.superview!.bounds.intersection(subview.frame)
if !intersection.equalTo(subview.frame) { 
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check if part of the subview is out of bounds of its super view, try this:

in case of x axis

```
if subview.frame.maxX >= superview.bounds.maxX {
    your code 
}
```

```
if subview.frame.minX <= superview.bounds.minX {
    your code
}
```

you can try the same for y axis, replace minX and maxX to minY and maxY